# Adding Description to each Tuple object?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a tuple of :

```
var a = new Tuple<int, int, int>(1,2,3);
```

My question :

is there any way (by  `/// remark`  or something else ), to add a short description to the object types ?

the first 3 **int's** can be confusing....

How can I know that item1 is refering to "age" and not to "Number of fingers" ?

[image]

Comment: Your code won't compile. Fourth parameter is int you are passing Product

Comment: Switch to F# and use records? ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The `Tuple` class is only intended to be used internally within a method; if you intend to make the data available publicly, you should define a `class` or `struct` with properties for each of your values.

However, if you want to give meaningful names to your values, you could use anonymous types instead. These are *constrained* (not just intended) to only be used internally within a method.

```
var a = new { Name = "ABC", Age = 33, NumberOfFingers = 10 };
int age = a.Age;
```

[image: Anonymous type]

**Edit**: If you’re convinced you want to return a tuple from your method, then my suggestion would be to explain its structure within the documentation for the return value of your method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves personal information about the person.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A tuple containing the following information:
/// <list type="bullet">
/// <item><see cref="Tuple{T1,T2,T3}.Item1"/>: The name of the person.</item>
/// <item><see cref="Tuple{T1,T2,T3}.Item2"/>: The age of the person.</item>
/// <item><see cref="Tuple{T1,T2,T3}.Item3"/>: The number of fingers the person has.</item>
/// </list>
/// </returns>
public Tuple<string, int, int> GetPerson()
{
    return Tuple.Create("ABC", 33, 10);
}
```

If you want it to show up in IntelliSense, place your explanation in the `<summary>`.

Comment: @dougles Ituples can also be used as a return TYPE of a function - so I wont need to create a class in a middle. I can write a function of  : `public Tuple<int,int> myFunc (){}`

Comment: They are a regular type just like any other, so they can be return values. However whether you *should* use them for return values, is a completely different topic. If the method is a public one, it's better to use an explicit class.

Comment: @douglas I know these Anonymous types. however , I cant use var as a return type of a function ( only dynamic)  and my main goal is to have  an object as a return type of a function. Thanks:)

Comment: That’s why I said “intended”. It is considered sloppy to expose data structures whose names are not self-documenting. This is akin to defining a class named `MyClass`, and properties named `MyProperty1`, `MyProperty2`, etc.

Comment: You’re welcome :-) (Correctness apart, I’ve had situations where I needed to do something similar due to time constraints. When I later had time to go back and try to document my code, I used the approach of documenting the _methods_ which have tuples as parameters or return types.)

Comment: Current editors process doc comments beyond the summary tag. This makes it attractive to also use doc comments for internal members.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible - you can't document the passed in parameters.

This is one of the big disadvantages of using `Tuple` - the meaning of the values is rather opaque.

I suggest writing a class/struct with meaningful names and using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I think it's worth mentioning in case anyone unfamiliar with `tuple`s stumbles upon it, but you can now name the `tuple`'s fields (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)).

I'm not sure how to reference them in the method's `<summary>` or `<remarks>` tags, but if you add the names to the return type of your method, other parts of your code can use them as well!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a tuple or a dynamic type, we can now (.NET 6 and above) also use records for such cases.

```
public class Program
{
    private record class Person(string Name, int Age, int Fingers); 
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person a = new("Peter", 36, 10);
    }
}
```

If you need further description beyond variable names, you can also add xml code docs to these record.

See also: [Records on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record)